# angular-bootstrap-calendar disabledDates or blackout dates

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I am using the wonderful https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar.
Is there a way to mark a range as disabled-dates?  Maybe set the cal-day cells in a specific color?

Example:
{"startsAt":"2016-11-02T00:00:00.000Z", "endsAt":"2016-11-10T00:00:00.000Z", "disabled":true}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cell-modifier option to do this, there is an example here: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=cell-modifier